# Verbreitung und Verwendungsbeispiele von "sein"-Auslassung

Tags: ellipsis

Ab und zu treffe ich Situationen und Kontexte, wo "sein" ausgelassen wurde.
Z.B. "das der Schlüssel" (https://youtu.be/Xcqcni1PcFo?list=RDbY6059rr7BU&t=133 ) , "das doch nix neues". 
Inwiefern ist das verbreitet in der Umgangssprache? Gibt es vielleicht typische Beispiele und Situationen?

Answer (score 7):

Das'der fälische Dialekt. Vom Ruhrgebiet bis Berlin verbreitet.

*Ist* wird zu *is* und weiter zu *s* reduziert. Nach *s* am vorhergehenden Wortende fällt es schließlich komplett weg. Allerdings nur, wenn dadurch keine Mehrdeutigkeiten entstehen.

> Was'n das? *(Was ist denn das?)*
>
> 's schwer. *(Das ist schwer.)*
>
> Links isser lang! *(Links ist er lang!)*

Comment: Alternativ ursprünglich *da is* > *da's*? Besonders in "das der Schlüssel", bzw. eher *da-s-'a Schlüssel*, sonst *Da! Der Schlüssel!*. Die Artikel in *d-* hatten ältere Artikel, *s-*, ersetzt, also ehemals *da sa Sluzel*?

Comment: Ich, ein Berufspendler, kann bestätigen, dass die Auslassung oder Verkürzung aller Formen von _sein_ ganz stark in Magdeburg und Umgebung verbreitet ist. Richtung Osten hin, so etwa kurz hinter Genthin, tritt es nicht mehr auf.